# sum of logarithms

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have to solve find the value of
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n/2} k\log k$$
as a part of question.

How should I proceed on this ?

Comment: @user8250: It's submission or summation.

Comment: I may be asking a silly question, but what is a "submission"?

Comment: @DJC srry :) it was a typo .... i meant sigma and i am reading more on how to use tags to write equations here....

Comment: Just checking! :)

Comment: I doubt you will find a "closed form" formula. Maybe an asymptotic approximation?

Comment: $log(1^1) + log(2^2) + log(3^3) + ... + log((n/2)^{n/2}) = log(1*4*27*...)$?

Comment: Can I create an upper bound of it ?? I reached the same stage as @The Chaz

Comment: Just an idea if anybody could expand on it .... We can write k as n/2 in each of them .... then it would be that                       O(n/2 * log((n/2)factorial)) ..... Can anybody concise this expression more....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Got it.  The constant in Moron's answer is $C = \log A$, where $A$ is the [Glaisher-Kinkelin constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glaisher%E2%80%93Kinkelin_constant).  Thus $C = \frac{1}{12} - \zeta'(-1)$.

The expression $H(n) = \prod_{k=1}^n k^k$ is called the [hyperfactorial](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Hyperfactorial.html), and it has the known asymptotic expansion

$$H(n) = A e^{-n^2/4} n^{n(n+1)/2+1/12} \left(1 + \frac{1}{720n^2} - \frac{1433}{7257600n^4} + \cdots \right).$$
Taking logs and using the fact that $\log (1 + x) = O(x)$ yields an asymptotic expression for the OP's sum
$$\sum_{k=1}^n k \log k = C - \frac{n^2}{4} + \frac{n(n+1)}{2} \log n + \frac{\log n}{12} + O \left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right),$$ 
the same as the one Aryabhata obtained with Euler-Maclaurin summation.

---

*Added*: Finding an asymptotic formula for the hyperfactorial is Problem 9.28 in *Concrete Mathematics* (2nd ed.).  The answer they give uses Euler-Maclaurin, just as Aryabhata's answer does.  They also mention that a derivation of the value of $C$ is in N. G. de Bruijn's *[Asymptotic Methods in Analysis](http://books.google.com/books?id=_tnwmvHmVwMC&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false)*, $\S$3.7.

Comment: +1: Very nice ! :-) I am surprised the Plouffe inverter does not have this, though.

Comment: @Moron: Thanks! It's satisfying to have finally figured out what that constant is. :)

Comment: @Moron: It looks like Plouffe does have it (or a scaled version of it) after all.  The numerical estimate I was using before wasn't precise enough.

Comment: I see. I was about to suggest maybe you should add it there :-)

Comment: I suppose one proof of this would be to start from $\zeta'(s) = -\sum \log k/k^s$ for $Re(s) \gt 1$ and extend it for all $s$ (which can be done using Euler McLaurin I believe), similar to the Riemann Zeta function.

Comment: @Moron: That sounds like it would work.

Answer (score 6):

Here is an asymptotic expression using [EulerMcLaurin Summation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula).

$$ \sum _{k=1}^{n} k \log k = \int_{1}^{n} x \log x\ \text{d}x + (n\log n)/2 + C' + (\log n + 1)/12+ \mathcal{O}(1/n^2)$$

$$ = n^2(2 \log n - 1)/4 + (n\log n)/2 + (\log n)/12 + C + \mathcal{O}(1/n^2)$$

for some constant $C$.

Comment: +1, although I get $C = \frac{1}{4}$, $(\log n)/12$ rather than $(\log n)/18$, and $O(\frac{1}{n^2})$.  (And I have verified this numerically.)

Comment: @MIke: You are correct. I have edited the answer. Thanks. That C=1/4 would need a proof, but that is a neat value for that constant.

Comment: @Moron: You're right to be suspicious of $C = 1/4$.  It's not correct.  The value of $C$ to six decimal places appears to be $0.248755$ - close to $1/4$ but not quite $1/4$.  I'm not sure how to prove that or get an explicit expression, though.

Comment: @Mike: Perhaps the Plouffe inverter has something. We would probably need more than 6 digits though.

Comment: I tried Plouffe, with the more precise estimate $0.24875448644$, but I didn't get anything exact.  Just so you know, this number comes from using Mathematica to find the difference between the OP's sum and your estimate for large values of $n$.

Comment: @Mike: There is an infinite series representation using the $B_{2k}$ which comes from the Euler McLaurin formula. It might be easier to use that to calculate the expression and might also lead us to a "closed" form expression. It is very similar (but not quite the same) to the series we get for $\sum \log k$ which gives us the Stirling's constant $\sqrt{2\pi}$, I believe.

Comment: I tried that, but I got $1/4 + \sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac{B_{2k}}{(2k)!} (2k-3)!$, which doesn't converge.  I could have made a mistake, though.

Comment: @Mike: You are right that it does not converge! I didn't actually try to work it out. Sorry about that.

Comment: But you're right that the same procedure for finding Stirling's constant ought to work here.  There's got to be a way to get this! :)